# "Simple" condition that would prove a function transcendental

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, transcendental-functions

I conjectured that for every algebraic function $f(x)$ that is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, its $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ is either $\infty$, $-\infty$, or a finite value, so:

> If $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$ and its $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ is not $\infty$, $-\infty$, nor a finite value, then $f(x)$ is transcendental.

If this is true, how could it be proved?

This question was asked on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375397/simple-condition-that-would-prove-a-function-transcendental).

Comment: I haven't given this any thought, at least not at this time, but I am curious about the hypothesis of "differentiable". I don't see how differentiability would play a role that isn't already taken care of by only the assumption of continuity. What is your reason for including "differentiable"?

Comment: I just wanted to get rid of certain piecewise functions.

Comment: How about a function whose graph is a sine-wave-like chain of, say, circular arcs (though not semi-circles, as this would break differentiability)? It'd be differentiable everywhere, have no limits at $\pm\infty$ due to oscillation, yet would be algebraic.

Comment: @Blue ... that sequence of semicircles is not allowed by "algebraic".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function  See the solution at https://mathoverflow.net/a/375400/454

Comment: @GEdgar: I should've said that the chain of arcs corresponds to a "piecewise-algebraic" function. I guess this doesn't count. Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Note: An accepted answer to this question is found at: ["Simple" condition that would prove a function transcendental](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703824/simple-condition-that-would-prove-a-function-transcendental)

Iosif Pinelis's answer:

> $\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Your conjecture is true. Indeed, suppose
> that a function $f\colon\R\to\R$ is continuous and algebraic, so that
> $$\sum_{j\in[n]_0}p_j(x)f(x)^j=0\tag{1}$$ for all $x\in\R$, where
> $[n]_0:=\{0,\dots,n\}$, $n$ is a natural number, and, for each
> $j\in[n]_0$, $p_j$ is a polynomial function of some degree $m_j$, so
> that for some real $a_j\ne0$  $$p_j(x)=(a_j+o(1))x^{m_j}\tag{2}$$ as
> $x\to\infty$.
>
> Suppose now that for some real $c$ and some sequence $(x_m)$ in $\R$
> converging to $\infty$ we have $f(x_m)\to c$. Then, by (1) and (2),
> $$p(c):=\sum_{j\in J}a_j c^j=0,\tag{3}$$ where $J$ is the (nonempty)
> set of all $j\in[n]_0$ such that for all $i\in[n]_0$ we have $m_j\ge
> > m_i$. So, $c$ must be in the finite set of the roots of the polynomial
> $p$.
>
> On the other hand, if your conjecture were false, then, by the
> intermediate value theorem, there would be infinitely (even
> uncountably) many real $c$ such that for some sequence $(x_m)$ in $\R$
> converging to $\infty$ we have $f(x_m)\to c$.
>
> So, your conjecture is true.